# Show that R is an equivalence relation on the set of all bit strings

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

Let R be a relation consisting of all pairs (a, b) where a and b are bit strings of length at least five and a and b agree in their first five bits. Show that R is an equivalence relation on the set of all bit strings of length at least five.

Two strings a and b agree in their first k bits if the first k bits of a are equal to the first k bits of b.

I understand that in order for a relation to be considered an equivalence relation, it must be reflexive, symmetric, and transitive. But I am not sure how I would show this given the question above. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, go one at a time.  First of all, reflexive:  is it true that the first $5$ bits of $a$ are equal to the first five bits of $a$?  Next do symmetric, and then transitive.

Comment: @lulu I feel like I'm overthinking this a bunch. Am I basically just to show each of the equivalence relation properties? I'm not exactly sure how to go about proving them when I am working with a relation like this.

Comment: Yes. You must check each of the three properties.  And that's all you have to do!  As my "reflexive" example illustrates, these three checks are each quite easy.

Comment: @lulu I understand your reflexive example but am not really sure how it would translate to symmetric and transitive. I think I am getting stuck on the fact that the strings only agree in their first 5 bits and could be longer than that and I am not sure how to prove something like that.

Comment: @Dash: If $a$ has the same first $5$ bits as $b$, does $b$ have the same first $5$ bits as $a$? If $a$ and $b$ have the same first $5$ bits, and $b$ and $c$ have the same first $5$ bits, do $a$ and $c$ have the same first $5$ bits?

Comment: Just go slowly.  Symmetry:  If $a=a_1a_2\cdots $ has the same first $5$ characters as $b=b_1b_2\cdots$ then that means that $a_1=b_1,a_2=b_2, a_3=b_3, a_4=b_4, a_5=b_5$.  Now write our what it would mean for $b$ to have the same first five characters as $a$.

Comment: But, really, just think about what it means.  If you have the same initials as your friend, has your friend got the same initials as you?  If you have the same initials as your friend, and your friend has the same initials as person X, have you got the same initials as $X$?